# plotting polygons in python using geopandas

Tags: polygon, geopandas

I have a data frame with latitude, longitude and annual consumption data. I am trying to plot the annual consumption data using GeoPandas with a quantile scheme by making a polygon column. I followed the following tutorial.
[enter link description here](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/choropleths.html)

I used the latitude and longitude data to make polygon shapes using the following code.

```
full_dataframe["geometry"] = Polygon(list(zip(full_dataframe["long"], full_dataframe["lat"])))

merged2 = GeoDataFrame(full_dataframe)

merged2.plot(column='annual_consume', scheme='quantiles', k=4, edgecolor='k', 
             cmap='OrRd', legend=True,
             legend_kwds={'loc': 'center left', 'bbox_to_anchor':(1,0.5)})
```

My data frame looks like below
[image]

The issue is, when I plot it, it looks like a big mess of interconnecting points. The boundaries are not seperated.

[image]

I want a similar boundary separation like the tutorial based on longitude and latitude data.

[image]

Comment: `full_dataframe["geometry"] = Polygon(list(zip(full_dataframe["long"], full_dataframe["lat"])))` assigns the same single polygon containing all lat/long points to all rows in the dataframe. without your original data and a [mre] we can't really help guide what you should be doing, but to me the plot you say you want looks like a GeoDataFrame with one polygon per row.

Comment: can you check the question again now? I hope it is more clear what I am asking.

Comment: In the linked tutorial, they read in a [shapefile](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/io.html#reading-spatial-data), which has shape definitions built in. It looks like you have point-wise data, which you're trying to associate with some geographical boundaries, but you don't have a shapefile. You need to go find a shapefile (.shp, .geojson, etc) to associate with your data. Then you'll need to [associate each point with a shape](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mergingdata.html), e.g. with `geopandas.sjoin`.

Comment: alternatively, you could just do a scatter plot with the lat/lon values. but as far as I can tell you don't have *any* polygon data - you're just drawing lines in between all your points, rolling that into a Polygon definition, and then assigning that single mess of a polygon to every row. If you want a choropleth, you'll need to find a shapefile online for the regions you're trying to plot.

Comment: it appears your data is in Belgium.  Just adding all points into a polygon in effectively random order (order in data frame) does not give a meaningful polygon associated with each measure.  it would make more sense to dissolve into defined regions of area or synthesise polygons that make sense (squares, hexagons).  Without access to some of the data it's not really possible to demonstrate